# Finding the curvature and torsion of a curve

Tags: geometry, curvature

[image]

[image]

For this question:

I'm not able to find what the torsion is for the curve gamma.

In my notes I'm given that first derivative of b, (b dot) =-tau multiplied by n.

so in the solution I don't understand why they are working out n dot when we should be working out b dot and so torsion tau=-b dot/n. So I'm not able to understand what they have done to work out torsion. Why are they working out tau=n dot multiplied by b when according to my notes tau should be equal to -b dot/n?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should only care about what $\gamma'$ is; and for that, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is enough. For your third question, the $\langle, \rangle$ notation is just the dot product.

Comment: that's what I'm not able to understand how to work out gamma dash (the first derivative) when the gamma has an integral in its x and z components.

Comment: The derivative of the integral of $f$ is just $f$. This is because (roughly speaking) differentiation and integration are the "reverses" of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is any reasonable function, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \int_a^t f(u)du   \right) = f(t)
$$
This is the "[Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements)".

So, in your case
$$
\vec{\mathbf{t}} = \gamma'(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}
\left(  \sin \pi t^2, 1, \cos \pi t^2, \right)
$$

I expect you can take it from there.

As the comment said, the angle bracket in the last line is a dot product of two vectors: $\langle \mathbf u, \mathbf v \rangle = u_xv_x + u_yv_y + u_zv_x$.

There are several different formulas for torsion. One of them (the one you know, apparently) is 
$$
\tau = - \mathbf{N} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{B}}
$$
However, you also probably know one of the Serret-Frenet formulae, which says that
$$
\dot{\mathbf{N}} = \tau \mathbf{B} - \kappa \mathbf{T}
$$
If you take the dot product of this formula with $\mathbf{B}$, you get
$$
\dot{\mathbf{N}} \cdot \mathbf{B} = 
\tau (\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{B}) - \kappa (\mathbf{T} \cdot \mathbf{B}) =
\tau (1) - \kappa (0) = \tau
$$
so it's also true that $\tau = \dot{\mathbf{N}} \cdot \mathbf{B}$, and that's the formula they used in the solution you showed.

Comment: I understand upto that part however, I'm not able to understand how torsion has been calculated and so don't understand what the formula being used for  torsion as in the solution it differs from the one I'm given in my lecture notes. That the first derivative of b, (b dot) =-tau multiplied by n